# pandas isin based on common column for 2 different dataframes at row level

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes. Example:

```
DF1:

ID  Val1 VAl2
123  a    d
234  b    e
345  c    f

DF2:

ID  Val1 VAl2
234  b    d
345  c    f
567  k    l
123  b    d
```

I want to compare rows of DF2 with DF1 based on ID (Index for same ID value is different in both the DFs are different), and get output like:

```
Output:

ID   Val1 VAl2
NaN  NaN  d
NaN  NaN  NaN
567  k    l
NaN  b    NaN
```

So, where-ever values are similar based on ID is populated as NaN and the values that are different are populated as it is.

I tried to use:

```
DF2[~DF2.isin(DF1)]
```

But it compares based on index of dataframes.

I also tried:

```
DF2.isin(DF1.values.ravel())
```

But, it compares at individual value level in dataframe.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Set the index then use `eq`

```
df1.set_index('ID').eq(df2.set_index('ID'))
      Val1   VAl2
ID               
123  False   True
234   True  False
345   True   True
567  False  False
```

Comment: similar logic with mask gives the almost the expected output: `df2.set_index('ID').mask(df1.set_index('ID').eq(df2.set_index('ID'))).reset_index()` :)

Comment: @anky_91 Thanks for the response. Very close to what I was looking for. I also want to have ID as NaN, wherever DF2 id ID is present in DF1 as well.